# Checker board algorithm implementation

Tags: python, dynamic-programming

```
def Checker(n):
    p = [[7,3,5,6,1],[2,6,7,0,2],[3,5,7,8,2],[7,6,1,1,4],[6,7,4,7,8]]  #profit of each cell
    cost = [[0 for j in range(n)] for i in range(n)]
    w = [[0 for j in range(n)] for i in range(n)]   #w[i, j] store the column number (j) of the previous square from which we moved to the current square at [i,j]
   for j in range(1,n):
       cost[1][j] = 0
   for i in range(2,n):
        for j in range(1,n):
            max = cost[i-1][j] + p[i-1][j]
            w[i][j] = j
            if (j > 1 and cost[i-1][j-1] + p[i-1][j-1] > max):
                max = cost[i-1][j-1] + p[i-1][j-1]
                w[i][j] = j-1
            if (j < n and cost[i-1][j+1] + p[i-1][j+1] > max):
                max = cost[i-1][j+1] + p[i-1][j+1]
                w[i][j] = j+1
            cost[i][j] = max
            print cost[i][j]
    maxd = cost[1][1]
    maxj = 1
    for j in range(2,n):
        if cost[1][j] >maxd:
            maxd = cost[1][j]
            maxj = j
    print "Maximum profit is: ",maxd
    printsquares(w,n,maxj)

def printsquares(w,i,j):
    if i == -1:
        return
    print "Square at row %d and column %d"%(i,j)
    printsquares(w,i-1,w[i][j])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print "5*5 checker board problem"
    n = 5
    Checker(n)
```

The above program is implementation of checker board algorithm in python.
when i run the above code the following error is shown:

> if (j < n and cost[i-1][j+1] + p[i-1][j+1] > max): IndexError: list
>   index out of range

what am i doing wrong and any one would propose solution for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid the IndexError exceptions,

```
if (j < n and cost[i-1][j+1] + p[i-1][j+1] > max):
  max = cost[i-1][j+1] + p[i-1][j+1]
```

should be written:

```
if (j < n-1 and cost[i-1][j+1] + p[i-1][j+1] > max):
  max = cost[i-1][j+1] + p[i-1][j+1]
```

and

```
printsquares(w,i-1,w[i][j])
```

becomes

```
printsquares(w,i-1,w[i-1][j])
```

But as said by other fellows, I'm not certain that the algorithm is correctly implemented.

Answer (score 0):

You're pretty much trying to do this:

```
L = range(5)
print L[5+1]
```

At `cost[i-1][j+1]`.

There is no 6th element. There's only five. Hence the `IndexError`.

As for a solution, you probably only want `n` and not `n+1` if you want the last element. However, I'm not 100% sure.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to adapt an algorithm from a language where lists start from 1 whereas they start from 0 in Python. As far I as checked, you never access `cost[i][0]`.